# How to convert any date (format = Y-m-d H:i:s) to unix timestamp in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to convert selected date into unix timestamp and pass to api

Comment: yourDate.getTime() / 1000 = unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some library which does it for you:

http://momentjs.com/

https://date-fns.org/